# Reduce lives by 1 every wrong guess

Tags: python

```
import random
# Make a list of different animal or anything.
word_list = ["ardvark", "baboon", "camel"]


# Use the random module to randomly pick an animal in the list.
random_word = random.choice(word_list)


# print the choosen word.
print(random_word)


display = ["_" for _ in random_word]

lives = 6

# empty guess.
guess = ''
# empty guess list.

# while loop in display.
while "_" in display:
    # ask the user to guess a letter from the chosen word.
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    # get the range and the len of the chosen word.
    for i in range(len(random_word)):
        # if the letter(guess) is equal to one of the letter in the chosen word.
        if random_word[i] == guess:
            display[i] = random_word[i]
    if random_word != guess:
        lives -= 1
        print(lives)
    # print the display with the right letter.
    print(" ".join(display))
```

I was expecting that with every wrong answer, my life would go down by 1. But instead of every right or wrong answer, my life goes down by one. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

RESULTS:
baboon

Guess a letter: b

5

b _ b _ _ _

Guess a letter: r

4

b _ b _ _ _

Guess a letter:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's subtracting a life because your input of `b` is not equal to the word `baboon`, like you said in the line `if random_word != guess:`**

My assumption is that you meant it to only subtract a life only if the guessed word/letter isn't in the `random_word`. If this is correct, you can get the expected behavior by changing:

```
if random_word != guess:
        lives -= 1
```

to:

```
if guess not in random_word:
        lives -= 1
```

Which gives us this output:

```
camel
Guess a letter: c
c _ _ _ _
Guess a letter: b
5
c _ _ _ _
Guess a letter: a
c a _ _ _
Guess a letter: d
4
c a _ _ _
...
```

Comment: Thank you, lol I actually tried this earlier and I got the same result. Well, I guess I placed it in the wrong place. 
Thanks for helping a noobie 